# How can I create an ALIAS in SQL Server to SharePoint connect

Tags: 2007, sql-server

I need to create the ALIAS SQL01-ST01\ST01 for a Sharepoint 2007 FARM to connect on standalone SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, I tried to create an alias, but I can only connect locally, if I try to connect to another server I can not.

So I tried to create a CNAME in DNS Services > Forward Lookup Zones, but I can only create it with the name SQL01-ST01, but I need to create it with the "\ST01"

Could someone help me to create the complete alias SQL01-ST01\ST01?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the aliases for SP SQL i usually do it on the server itself. From start--> run execute 'cliconfg' from there you can set up the alias (second tab). You need to repeat the process on all servers in the farm.

Now  if you run the 64 bit version of Microsoft server you might need to set up 64bit Alias. to do that ensure you run the cliconfig.exe from those both folders:

- C:\Windows\System32 - this sets 64bit alias
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64 - this sets 32bit alias.

Comment: Thank you Marek, your tip worked.

just one more question

That Cluster server will be shut down forever

I intend to do this:

1 - Stop Sharepoint services
3 - Backups of Sharepoint databases
4 - Restores databases in the new instance of SQL Stand Alone
2 - shut down the SQL Cluster Server
3 - Delete entries named SQL01-ST01\ST01 in Active Directoty
4 - On the Sharepoint server create a SQL01-ST01\ST01 Alias pointing to the new stand alone server
5 - Start Sharepoint services again

Sharepoint will normally recognize the new SQL Server instance when I start the services

Comment: Yes that is exactly what needs to be done. In fact best practice for SP is to set up the alias in every installation as SPDB (or something similar) this way when you change you backend you don't have to have aliases like oldDbClusterName alias to : NewDBName. You just update the alias from old to new server. Word of caution, Microsoft doesn't support restoring SP config DB. if you want to stay clear of contractual issues you should move the DB files and mount the DB in new server without backup-restore. (in practice on my QA systems I have restored config db multiple times without any problems

Comment: Marek, you really helped me a lot.
Thank you very much,

Comment: You are welcome, If it all works for you then don't forget about marking it as answer. With regards to the SPConfigDB restore, you are on 2007 so you are out of bounds for support so probably you can do whatever you want with config db. unless you are some big enterprise with special support contract MS will refuse to support you.

Comment: No way, my Enterprise is very small. 
But I will do what you said, to be sure, I will move or copy the DB files
Anyway, thanks again Marek